# TYPO3 Fluid File Collection Metadata

Tags: typo3, metadata, fluid, fal, tx-dce

I want to access files and associated metadata from a folder based file collection, but debug says metaDataLoaded=false and metaDataProperties is empty.

Here my code fluid code from my DCE:

```
{namespace dce=ArminVieweg\Dce\ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
    <f:for each="{field.fileCollection}" as="collection">
        <f:debug>{collection}</f:debug>
        <f:for each="{collection.items}" as="item">
            <f:format.html>{item.name}</f:format.html>
            <f:debug>{item.metaDataProperties}</f:debug>
        </f:for>
    </f:for>    
</f:section>
```

Why is the metadata not loaded? How can i access the metadata of a file?

thanx in advance,

Jan

Answer (score 1):

use `properties` there all properties of image and metadata are merged together.

`<f:debug>{item.properties}</f:debug>`

Comment: Thank you very much. 

It seems the metadata are loaded on access of item.properties, so debug doesn't show them...

Comment: I adjusted the awnser. The debug line was wrong. This should give some results